# ASP.NET MVC application hosted on IIS failed on stress test with 50 users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, iis, stress-testing

I have an angular 7 app built in an ASP.NET MVC application and hosted on IIS

I tested my application on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ and get 88/100 score for loading speed

when a single user open the link for the first time the index page will load fast, my problem appears when 50 users tries to make a stress test over my home page link , the page will die and take minutes to load
NB: I made a stress test using https://app.loadimpact.com

when a single user access the home page the network page shows
[image]

when 50 users accesses the home page the network page shows
[image]

I want to have my website load fast even when stress tested with 50 users or more! Please any help regarding this issue ??

Comment: I don't think we can help you since we have no idea what the page is doing. It could be an IIS setting, a .net code optimization, a database code optimization. It could even just be the server that isn't fast enough.

Comment: Could you plase tell me the IIS environment? Do you host your IIS on the server or windows10? As far as I know, the winodws 10 has the current request limit. The IIS could only handle 3 requests at same time.

Comment: @BrandoZhang we are using IIS 10 hosted on windows server 2016 with IOZoom provider ! is there any limitations for those versions ?? what are the settings that we need to look for ?

Comment: As far as I know,  the blue part (content download) is very large. It seems that there is limit for your server's network. I suggest you could  check if his server has the network limit.

Comment: @BrandoZhang Is there any links or documentation regarding server network limitation issues that can help ?

Comment: In my opinion, you should contact with your server provider or the network provider company to know your server's network uplink and downlink speed.